# Copy data from one blob storage to another blob storage

Tags: azure-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, eventtrigger

My requiremnt is like that I have two storage account sa01 and sa02. Let say Sa01 having 10 files and Sa02 also having 10 files at time 01:00 AM. Now I have uploaded 4 more files at 1:15AM in sa01 and my copy activity wil automatically runs beacause I am implemented the event trigger. So It will insert the 4 files to sa02.

Question - It will insert the 4 files and also updating the previous (10) files also, so I am getting 14 files at time 01:15 AM,and requriment say that if 10 files uploaded already at 01:00 AM and 4 files which is latest can inserted in sa02.

See the timings in image I have just uploaded one file all the files time is modified.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Data Share](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-share/) is one good way to accomplish this. It is typically used to sync storage with a partner company. But you can sync in your own subscription. There is no code to write. There is a UI and a sync schedule.

Comment: Hello Greg, Does Data share able to support incremental type of data the scenario I mentioned above does this service able to fulfill. & coming to cost wise which is cheaper ADF or Azure data share. Data size is 1TB (including files, folder in ADLS gen2) . I haven't aware about this service can you answer those question? it is really helpful for me. My primary way is to use ADF,but data share able to handle incremental data and cheaper than ADF then I can convince my client on that service.

Comment: @anuj yes. See mentions of incremental here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-share/terminology

Comment: You can go to the Azure Data Share pricing page to understand the model. But you May have to try it to understand precise costs. I’m not sure which one will be cheaper for your datasets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Metadata activity to get the lastModified of the destination folder.

- In your Copy activity, put dynamic content in the
  *Filter by last modified: start time field*.  Choose the lastModified field output from the    Metadata activity.

Only files in the source newer than the destination's lastModified will be copied.

Metadata activity is tiny fractions of a penny in cost.

Comment: Hello Jason I tried like get metadata -->dataset (sa02) -- > copyactivity source sa01 in that start time (utcnow()) end time(@activity('Get Metadata1').output).
I am getting below error

Comment: "Code": 11101,
            "Message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidValueInPayload,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to convert the value in 'modifiedDatetimeEnd' property to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' type. Please make sure the payload structure and value are correct.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DataContracts,''

Comment: If I understood correctly, then you want files in sa01 that are newer than the newest in sa02.  So in the copy activity, the start date is the newest in sa02 (getMetadata('myname'),output.lastModified) and the end date is utcnow() (or if you might be adding more files during the pipeline run then better use pipeline().TriggerTime).   You missed the .lastModified from the metadata output - this page is useful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#get-a-folders-metadata